# Pylint with sniffer not using updated source files

Tags: python, pylint, sniffer

I am using Pylint and Nose along with sniffer to lint and test my python application on every save. This is sniffer in case you are unaware https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sniffer

Here is the runnable responsible for running nosetests and pylint from **scent.py** file for sniffer

```
from sniffer.api import * # import the really small API
from pylint import lint
from subprocess import call
import os
import nose

@runnable
def zimmer_tests(*args):
    command = "nosetests some_module/test --nologcapture --with-coverage --cover-config-file=zimmer_coverage_config"

    lint.Run(['some_module/app'], exit=False)
    return call(command, shell=True) == 0
```

Here, first `lint.Run()` runs pylint on my app. Then nosetest is executed on the app using `call()`

The Problem is that after I save the file nosetests run on updated version of the file however Pylint uses the same old version. I have to restart sniffer every time for pylint to get new version of files.

I assume this is not a problem of sniffer's configuration since nosetests is able to get the new version of file every time. Still I am not sure.

My pylintrc file is almost the same we get from generate command `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc` with some minor application specific tweaks.

Comment: You are running pylint in a still running process. If something got imported it will be cached on the second import it will be taken from the cache. Node on the other hand is started as it's own process and starts with an empty modules cache every time. You might want to start pylint by command line as well.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks a lot! calling directly from command line worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @KlausD. in comments, the `lint.Run()` was using files from cache as it was being called from a still running process. Calling pylint from command line worked as expected.

Here is the modified code

```
@runnable
def zimmer_tests(*args):
    command_nose = "nosetests some_module/test --nologcapture --with-coverage --cover-config-file=zimmer_coverage_config"
    command_lint = "pylint some_module"
    call(command_lint, shell=True)
    return call(command_nose, shell=True) == 0
```